# HTML - Python How to access form elements?

Tags: python, html, forms, input

Trying to build my own webmail client.
I get a template for the web part which look like this

```
<form name="input" action="test2.py" methog="get" class="form">
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="Pass" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit" id="login-button">Login</button>
</form>
```

Would like to get the input on click on the button of Username && Pass via GET method to fill this bunch of code in python.

```
user = ???(Username)
pass = ???(Pass)
```

And print to a new empty html file the value of thoses var.

New to python so everything I try seem to fail.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#using-the-cgi-module

Comment: Excatly what I did... but seem not working on click. Do I need some Js behind ?

Comment: I don’t think so.. could you paste your current python code here?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `method="post"`, it won't work with a `GET` method (however it is misspelled, you wrote "methog").

Answer (score 0):

Write `import request` without quotes at the top of your python file.
Now use `request.inputForm['name']` without quotes to access form elements where name is the element name.